# Matrix multiplication in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I try to multiply two matrices in a python program using Keras.

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(10,500)
B = np.random.rand(500,6000)

x = K.placeholder(shape=A.shape)
y = K.placeholder(shape=B.shape)
xy = K.dot(x, y)

xy.eval(A,B)
```

I know this cannot work, but I also don't know how I can make it work.

Comment: Why do you need Keras to do this? You can do this with numpy

Comment: Yes, but I'm already working with Keras in my program and Keras has GPU support.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use a variable instead of a place holder.

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(10,500)
B = np.random.rand(500,6000)

x = K.variable(value=A)
y = K.variable(value=B)

z = K.dot(x,y)

# Here you need to use K.eval() instead of z.eval() because this uses the backend session
K.eval(z)
```

Comment: Great! Works beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing, if it worked for you please make sure to accept the answer :) Thank you

Comment: @snoozzz since the answer has resolved your issue, kindly *accept* it - answers take up valuable time for respondents

Comment: Yes, but note, if the goal is to perform a matrix product as a layer of a model then you should not use the backend. keras.backend will just refer the operation to the backend framework, and that causes problems when saving the model. Instead you should use keras.layers.dot which is specifically for performing tensor products in a model layer. https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot